# Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@43756de8 is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have already gone through few forums on this error, but I don't find an solution for my problem.

```
Use Case:
-> Start an Activity1(Module1) -> Tap on a button on Activity1 screen to Start Activity2(Module2) 

-> Tap on Back button on Activity2 screen-> Confirm AlertDialog displayed with Yes or No option

-> Navigated to Activity1 screen (after YES button pressed - calling finish() to go back to previous activity/dismiss the Activity2 screen)

-> User is navigated to Activity 1 screen - Tap on a button(Activity1 screen) to Start Activity2 again

-> Tap on Back button on Activity2 screen - Noticing an error

Activity1 - in Main Application (built using Cordova)
Activity2 - Module2
```

Error:

> Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@43756de8 is not valid; is your activity running?

But why we get this error though I launch the Activity2 again?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Activity2.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);

AndroidManifest - Moduele2
          <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
        </activity>
```

I am suppose to display the popup every time when the user taps on back on Activity2 screen. Any thoughts why I get this exception?

Comment: are you using dialogfragment for alert dialog ?

Comment: new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext)
                .setTitle("Confirmation?")

Comment: Where is the `activityContext` you're passing to the dialog initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your activityContext does not refresh.

Check your activityContext for refreshing.

And You can try,, When tap on Back button on Activity2 screen

```
if(!MainActivity2.this.isFinishing()) {
    // Dialog.show()
}
```

Comment: I want to see your Activity2's code. Is it possible?